# How to add something to $request for the other controller on Laravel

Tags: php, object, collections, request, laravel-5.6

Laravel 5.6

```
web.php

Route::get('edit/{city}/{id}/{news}', 'Controller@edit');
```

Controller

```
public function edit_point_edit($city,$id,$news)
{

/* $request=collect(); */
/* try 1 */
        $request->request->add(['city' => $city,'id' => $id,'news' => $news]);
/* try 2 */       
        $request->merge(['city' => $city,'id' => $id,'news' => $news]);


      $test = App::call(Controller::class . '@test',[
              'Request' => $request,
            ]);
}
```

I got the error message 「Undefined variable: request 」 But I had the 「use Illuminate\Http\Request;」why I got the error message?

Does I need to declare the $request type first?
How can I declare the type of $request?

```
$request=collect(); -->fail  can pass but cannot send key value to next controller
$request=array();  ->error code 
Trying to get property 'request' of non-object


$request = new stdClass();
$request = (object)[];
=>error code   
Undefined property: stdClass::$request
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move the method in 'other controller' to a service and inject that service in both the controllers and call the service method in both places? I assume the goal here is to reuse the 'other controller' method.

Comment: Yes. I want to use the 【test】controller many times and many places. So I need to make a empty and fill some key and value to the $request for the 【test】 controller

Comment: Better way to achieve that is by moving the code to a service class, controllers should not call other controllers. This is by design the behavior of any MVC. Controllers should generally be used to handle your HTTP requests and if you have to implement some shared logic which should be used by several controllers / modules, move that code to a commonly accessible place, in this case a service would be the best option.